# How to diagnose what's causing InnoDB to run out of space?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, digital-ocean

Site used to go down frequently on a near daily basis and is on Digitalocean VPS

Based on some suggestions I got on DO forum, I ran mysqltuner and increased innodb buffer pool size to 341M and innodb log file size to 64M

Since then the site goes down less but it still does every once in a while like last night.

There are plently of 'InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool' in the [mysql error log - pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TpAfNDbD)

I've assigned swap space and I've ran netstat, vmstat etc too and everything seems alright.

But clearly I'm running out of memory as the logs suggest. How do I diagnose whats causing my server to run out of memory? Whether its a faulty plugin or apache or something else causing the issue instead of just upgrading the droplet?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115513/discussion-on-question-by-sam-how-to-diagnose-whats-causing-innodb-to-run-out-o).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try MySQL Workbench which is free and quite useful for tasks like this.

Comment: Exactly what about MySQL Workbench would help in this situation?

Comment: Click on server status for infos about mem usage etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems like MYSQL is not getting enough memory to add to the buffer pool size. Setting up parameter need to be done with precaution if the values are too high you might have an issue with server hogging. InnoDB buffer pool size should be set to 50% of the available RAM in a low connection environment and 30% in a high connection environment. You can check more about the parameters here https://www.skynats.com/blog/mysql-server-optimization/

Comment: My InnoDB buffer pool size seems in line with your recommendations then. I'm on a 1GB memory droplet and my buffer pool size if 341mb

Answer (score 0):

2020-07-15T21:33:55.734143Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, **total size = 384M**, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-07-15T21:33:55.748097Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: **mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12**
2020-07-15T21:33:55.751593Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: **Cannot allocate memory** for the buffer pool

How much RAM do you have?  Either it is *very* tiny, or you have a lot of RAM taken up by other things.

Comment: I am on the $5 droplet by digital ocean with a memory of 1 GB



~# free -m

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem:            985         512         105          26         366         293

Swap:          1023          88         935

Comment: @Sam - Is MySQL then only thing in the droplet?

Comment: No. It has wordpress installed on it and has a lot of content on the wordpress site. Nearly a thousand post with images. However this same droplet was easily handling around 5x the traffic it is getting now and did not go down

Comment: Something is chewing up the RAM; we need to figure that out.

Comment: Yes. Rick, any way to find that out? I turned off the performance schema too in mysqld yet the site went down again

Comment: Did you change versions recently?

Comment: No I haven't changed versions